# Pacotes não restauram NugetPackage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Apos atualizar o VS2017 para a versão 15.5.1 este projeto não restaura mais os pacotes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tentei remover os pacotes e instalar novamente mas não deu certo, reinstalei o VS não deu certo tbm, pesquisei um pouco e tinha algumas soluções disendo para abrir o VS sem o projeto, abrir o Package Manager Console e apos abrir o projeto mas não deu certo tambem...

Comment: Deu Restore Packages? Qual é exatamente esse warning que ele esta falando?

Comment: quando tento dar um restore da esta msgn: The operation failed as details for project SingleSignOn.IdentityServer could not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> Solução encontrada no stack em inglês:

1.) Delete o diretório .vs na raiz da sua solution

2.) Abra abra o arquivo.config em todos os projetos e apgue todos os binding redirects.

3.) Apague os diretórios bin and obj de todos os projetos.

Obs.: Quando eu passei por isso bastou excluir o diretório .vs, fechar o VS e abrir novamente, que o restore voltou a funcionar. Se não resolver, vale seguir os outros passos.

[Link para a resposta original.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804551/the-nuget-packages-nightmare-in-vs-15-5-1)

> EDIT: 
>   Deve-se
>    evitar caracteres especiais no nome dos projetos, sollution e diretórios.

Comment: Não deu certo, tentei todos os passos....

Comment: Algum dos seus projetos ou solution possui algum caracter "especial" no nome? tipo um parenteses ou hífen?

Comment: o projeto tem um "." é (SingleSignOn.IdentityServer) a solution é so SigleSignOn

Comment: "." é comum por refletir o namespace, um colega aqui tinha comentado sobre o parentes

Comment: A pasta aonde esta o projeto tem parenteses ou tentar tirar isso...

Comment: Bahhh era isso mesmo foi que foi um doce muito obrigado salvo minha vida!!!

Comment: Vou adicionar a informação na resposta ;)